# Makefile is giving error while execution

Tags: c, makefile

I am executing below code in makefile:

```
### Get memory map and standard makefile ###
ifeq ($(CORTEX_R4),1)
SCATTER_FILE = scatter/boot_r4.scatter
else
ifeq ($(CORTEX_m0),1)
SCATTER_FILE = scatter/boot_m0.scatter
else
SCATTER_FILE = memory_map.scatter
endif
endif
BASE_PATH = .
include ./StdMakefile
### Make target ###
%.rom: %.elf
    touch $*.rom
    touch $*.itcm esw_host_def
    touch $*.erom
# First clear existing suffix rules, second defines build order so Pmap headers are built first
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: $(PMAP_LIB) .h .s .c .o
# Linker options
ifeq ($(CORTEX_R4),1)
LINKFLAGS = --map --noremove --entry 0x0 --scatter $(SCATTER_FILE) --info sizes,totals --list link_info.txt --elf
LINKLIB =
%.elf: %.o $(PMAP_LIB) $(LIB) $(INIT_LIB) $(TESTS_LIB) $(UNREMAP_LIB) $(EROMBOOT_LIB) $(USB_LIB) scatter/boot_r4.scatter
else 
ifeq ($(CORTEX_m0),1)
LINKFLAGS = --xref --elf --map --symbols --noremove --scatter $(SCATTER_FILE) --entry __main --info sizes,totals --list link_info.txt --elf 
LINKLIB =
%.elf: %.o $(PMAP_LIB) $(LIB) $(INIT_LIB) $(TESTS_LIB) $(UNREMAP_LIB) $(EROMBOOT_LIB) $(USB_LIB) memory_map.scatter
else
LINKFLAGS = --xref --elf --map --symbols --noremove --scatter $(SCATTER_FILE) --entry __main --info sizes,totals --list link_info.txt --elf 
LINKLIB =
%.elf: %.o $(PMAP_LIB) $(LIB) $(INIT_LIB) $(TESTS_LIB) $(UNREMAP_LIB) $(EROMBOOT_LIB) $(USB_LIB) memory_map.scatter
endif
endif
ifeq ($(CORTEX_R4),1)
    $(ARMLINK) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(INIT_DIR)/$(INIT_LIB)\(*\) $(LIB_DIR)/$(LIB) $(PMAP_DIR)/$(PMAP_LIB) $(TESTS_DIR)/$(TESTS_LIB)  $(LINKLIB)  ; \
else
ifeq ($(CORTEX_m0),1)
    $(ARMLINK) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(INIT_DIR)/$(INIT_LIB)\(*\) $(LIB_DIR)/$(LIB) $(PMAP_DIR)/$(PMAP_LIB) $(TESTS_DIR)/$(TESTS_LIB)  $(LINKLIB)  ; \
else
    $(ARMLINK) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(INIT_DIR)/$(INIT_LIB)\(*\) $(LIB_DIR)/$(LIB) $(PMAP_DIR)/$(PMAP_LIB) $(TESTS_DIR)/$(TESTS_LIB)  $(LINKLIB)  ; \
endif
endif
    cp $@ $*.elf2
# Libraries Included
$(LIB):
    cd $(LIB_DIR); $(MAKE) clean ; $(MAKE) $(LIB)
$(INIT_LIB):
    cd $(INIT_DIR); $(MAKE) clean ; $(MAKE) $(INIT_LIB)
$(PMAP_LIB):
    cd $(PMAP_DIR); $(MAKE) $(PMAP_LIB)
$(TESTS_LIB):
    cd $(TESTS_DIR); $(MAKE) $(TESTS_LIB)
$(UNREMAP_LIB):
##cd $(UNREMAP_DIR); $(MAKE) $(UNREMAP_LIB)
$(EROMBOOT_LIB):
    cd $(EROMBOOT_DIR); $(MAKE) clean ; $(MAKE) $(EROMBOOT_LIB)
$(USB_LIB):
##cd $(USB_DIR); $(MAKE) $(USB_LIB)
# Tidy up temporary build files/output files 
clean:
    cd $(LIB_DIR); $(MAKE) clean
    cd $(INIT_DIR); $(MAKE) clean
    cd $(PMAP_DIR); $(MAKE) clean
    cd $(TESTS_DIR); $(MAKE) clean
#rm -rf *.bin *.o *.elf *.elf2 *.list *.map *.rom? *.erom? *.ram?
```

The upper code is present in a makefile and used in flow for setup, While executing this is giving me below error:

Makefile:111: *** missing `endif'.  Stop.

Please let me know where I made the mistake.

Thanks a lot in advance....

Comment: Could be a problem in `StdMakefile` ?

Comment: Possibly the trailing backslashes on the few lines around `ifeq ($(CORTEX_R4),1)`?  It's probably joining the `else` and `endif`s on to the `$(ARMLINK)` lines.

Comment: there are some trailing `;`    (semicolons)  on some lines that should not be there.

Comment: near the top of the file there are some lines beginning with `$(ARMLINK)` but there is no preceeding `target:dependencies` statement

Comment: to execute a `make` file in a sub directory, the lines beginning with `cd` must be all within the same sub shell.  so this kind of line: `cd $(EROMBOOT_DIR); $(MAKE) clean ; $(MAKE) $(EROMBOOT_LIB)`  should be: `( cd $(EROMBOOT_DIR); $(MAKE) clean ; $(MAKE) $(EROMBOOT_LIB) )`   <-- notice the outside parens to keep it all within the same sub shell.   Without the parens, at the end of the `cd` returns to the same shell (no longer in the sub directory) then tries to execute the following commands

Comment: there is no chain of dependencies to cause the targets, like: `$(LIB)` to be evaluated.  suggest, as first target in makefile: `all: $(LIB) $(INIT_LIB) $(PNAP_LIB) $(TESTS_LIB) $(UNREMAP_LIB) $(EROMBOOT_LIB) $(USB_LIB)

Comment: targets that do not actually produce a file of the same name need to be preceeded (on the prior line, for instance, with `.PHONY: target`

Comment: the following macros have no value defined: `$(LIB)` `$(INIT_LIB)` `$(PNAP_LIB)` `$(TESTS_LIB)` `$(UNREMAP_LIB)` `$(EROMBOOT_LIB)`  `$(USB_LIB)`   so those targets will never be executed

Comment: the following macros have no value defined: `$(LIB_DIR)` `$(INIT_DIR)` `$(PMAP_DIR)` `$(TESTS_DIR)` `$(UNREMAP_DIR)` `$(EROMBOOT_DIR)` `$(USB_DIR)`  so the `cd` statements will (at best) change to the users home directory

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you,
Issue got resolved: It was due to the backslash so for that back slash a new line has to added just after that and few spaces were present in file instead of <TAB>.